# Generic Constraint in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, constraints

We currently created a table with generic ties... So there's column entity id and entity type ID along with some other data.

This is great because I wouldn't have to modify every table to include these columns.

The only issue is that there's no concrete constraint between the two tables.

Is there a way to create a constraint from table a, hard-coded entity type id to table b entity type id and table a, row id to table b entity id?

Thanks!

Comment: can you please provide schema of table for better understaning

Comment: Your question is absolutely unclear, but  - wild guessing - I'd suggest to read about constraints on VIEWs (with schema binding). You can add one view for each entity you are refering to. Such a design is - in most cases - something to avoid...